# MSR performance in x2APIC

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, interrupt-handling

As we know in x2APIC we use MSR instead of MMIO which is used by xAPIC. 
But according to my testing, I found that the speed of MSR access is much slower than MMIO.

For example, in my environment I wrote a simple test case as below:

```
static __inline__ void __loApicWrite
(
UINT32    * addr,
UINT32      value
)
{
__asm__ volatile
    (
    "movl    %1, %0"
    : "=m" (*(addr))
    : "ir" (value)
    );
}

void MSR_vs_MMIO(int way)
{
unsigned long a;
unsigned long b;
int i = 0;

msrReg = MSR_BASE_ADDRESS + (LOAPIC_ESR >> 4);

if (way == 0) /*MSR*/
    {
    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
        a = pentiumTscGet();    

        __asm__ volatile
        (
        "wrmsr\n"
        : : "c" (msrReg), "a"(0), "d" (0)
        );

        b =  pentiumTscGet();   

        if ( b > a ) 
            benchmark_record[i] = b - a ;
        }
    }

else         /*MMIO*/
    {
    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
        a =  pentiumTscGet();   

        __loApicWrite((UINT32 *)((0x82244000) + LOAPIC_ESR), 0);
        b =  pentiumTscGet();   

        if ( b > a )
            benchmark_record[i] = b - a ;
        }
    }

return;
```

}

If I run "MSR_vs_MMIO 0" , I got the number around 310.
And if I run "MSR_vs_MMIO 1", I got the number around 40.

I do the testing on my system with x2APIC enabled and disabled. When I boot my system with x2APIC enabled, I run the test "MSR_vs_MMIO 0", and when I boot my system with x2APIC disabled, I run the test "MSR_vs_MMIO 1". Then I collect the data and find the performance is huge different.

So seems that MMIO is about 8x faster than MSR access.

Is this result as expected?  And is there any documents on Intel manual (I searched but got no answer) to describe the performance difference between MSR in x2APIC and MMIO in xAPIC ?

Thanks.

Comment: It's probably unrelated to timing, but your inline asm is broken ;) Something that is related though is the fact that _"The WRMSR instruction is a serializing instruction"_ (quoted from the instruction set reference manual :))

Comment: Thank  you Jester, could you please point me of the broken inline asm?

Comment: You are zeroing `eax` and `edx` without telling the compiler, you need to clobber them, or better yet, pass in inputs as `"a" (0), "d" (0)` and delete the `movl`s.

Comment: Thank you Jester, I will update my inline asm . BTW, I checked the x2APIC  specification, and found a statment: "To allow for efficient access to the APIC registers in x2APIC mode, the serializing semantics of WRMSR are relaxed when writing to the APIC registers." .  So seems the problem is not caused by "serializing".

Comment: Where does the address 0x82244000 come from?

Comment: Possibly relevant: The MSR case does a memory clobber on each loop iteration. (Which is unnecessary, as far as I can tell.)

Comment: 0x82244000  is the virtual address which maps to the physical address of MMIO local APIC  base address .

Comment: @prl : I removed the clobber "memory" in my inline asm but got the similar test result. I have updated this in my question. Thanks .

Comment: I'm no expert in benchmarking but I do know that RDTSC is not serializing, so it can be problematic to use it to attempt to measure the latency of a single instruction. I don't know whether putting the RDTSCs outside the loop and dividing by 1000 would give more accurate results or not.

Comment: You might also consider measuring accesses to a variety of different APIC registers. They may not all be the same, and the manufacturer may be more likely to improve the performance of registers that are accessed in normal operation, as opposed to setup/initialization code or error cases.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your system is booted in x2apic mode, the MMIO interface to the APIC is disabled, so your MMIO code isn't actually accessing the APIC. See Intel SDM section 10.12.2.

Comment: Thanks prl for your comments.  Actually I do the testing on my system with x2APIC enabled and disabled. When I boot my system with x2APIC enabled, I run the test "MSR_vs_MMIO 0", and when I boot my system with x2APIC disabled, I run the test "MSR_vs_MMIO 1". Then I collect the data and find the performance is huge different.

Comment: Okay. You should say in your question that you reboot between the two tests.

Comment: @prl Is this also why I can't see APIC on device manager or !pcitree on my kaby lake system (because it uses x2APIC)